# Open suse Task Switching

Tags: opensuse

I have installed opensuse and the Alt  + tab key is not working to switch betwen the task.

Comment: you gotta be more specific. Alt + Tab works fine here.

Comment: We need a LOT more before we can help you. What version of OpenSUSE? What desktop environment (Gnome, KDE, etc)?  32 or 64 bit?

Comment: OpenSuse : 11.3 , Gnome , 32 bit

Comment: Instead of putting extra info in a comment, put it in your question its self.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Gnome but KDE 4.x has a `Configure window Behavior...` that allows me to control how I switch between tasks with `Alt+tab`, so that I can control how this is done.  Perhaps Gnome has something as well and nothing is currently configured.